# .Net Core C# Rest API "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I have a .Net Core C# API that looks like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{primaryKey}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseSingleX<ClassA>>> Update(Guid primaryKey, ClassA classA)
    {
        // Update database
    }
```

I try to do an update using the following code:

```
// Create a ClassA object and put some data in it
...

//GetServiceUrl() == return "http://localhost:9003/api/Configurations/";
serviceUrl = _shared.GetServiceUrl() + classA.PrimaryKey.ToString();
string requestBody = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(classA);
HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PutAsync(serviceUrl, requestContent);
Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var updatedResponse = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ResponseSingleX<ClassA>>(responseStream, _serializerOptions);
Assert.True(updatedResponse.Success);
var updatedClassA = updatedResponse.Element;
```

The problem I have is that responseMessage == "Method Not Allowed". Since this is literarily the first time I have ever used Rest (no matter the programming language), I am at a loss to why this does not work.

**UPDATE 0:**
I found my mistake. See my answer for the cause of the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: play with Fiddler proxy. it will  help you to debug things like this.

Comment: This is probably due to sending wrong type of http request. Please check are you using GET or PUT. For best control of sending requests you should use Postman or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. The class itself has an URL defined that defines additional parameters.

```
[Route("...") // <-This is what I missed
[ApiController]
public class SomeController
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [FromBody] attribute before ClassA:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{primaryKey}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseSingleX<ClassA>>> Update(Guid primaryKey, [FromBody] ClassA classA)
{
    // Update database
}
```